# twig and boolean

Tags: symfony, if-statement, twig

I have an Image class like this :

```
class Image {
private $color;
private $name;
private $gradient;
private $colorGradient;

function __construct() {
    $this->color = "FFFFFF";
    $this->name = "blanc";
    $this->gradient = false;
    $this->colorGradient = "";
}
```

in my controller I have this :

```
public function indexAction() {
    $image = new Image();

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($image)
            ->add('color', 'text')
            ->add('name', 'text')
            ->add('gradient', 'checkbox')
            ->add('colorGradient', 'text')
            ->getForm();

    return $this->render('CramifImageBuilderBundle:Builder:index.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

in index.html.twig I have this :

```
<form action="{{ path('cramif_image_builder_image_new') }}" method="post" {{  form_enctype(form) }}>
        {{ form_errors(form) }}

        {{form_row(form.color)}}
        {{form_row(form.name)}}

        <div id="gradient">
            {{form_row(form.gradient)}}
        </div>

        {% if form.gradient == true %}
            <div id="gradient_color">
                {{form_row(form.colorGradient)}}
            </div>
        {% endif %}

        <input id="submit" type='submit' value='Créer' />
    </form>
```

if gradient = true the checkbox is checked (good) with value='1'

```
<input id="form_gradient" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="1" required="required" name="form[gradient]">
```

if gradient = false the checkbox is not checked (good) with value = '1'

```
<input id="form_gradient" type="checkbox" value="1" required="required" name="form[gradient]">
```

The problem is whatever the value of gradient, it like gradient is true : so the colorgradient field is always displayed

Thank you

Comment: What happens if you omit `true` in the comparison, writing it like `{% if form.gradient %}`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't tested this yet, but try

```
{% if form.gradient.vars.checked %}
    <div id="gradient_color">
        {{ form_row(form.colorGradient) }}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: @mlwacosmos The form.gradient should always evaluate to true, because it exists.  The more I look at this the more it is confusing what the goal is.  Is the template only for new images?  Or is it intended to handle existing images as well?

Comment: In this case, the value of `form.gradient.vars.checked` could be set to `checked` and not `true`, and otherwise might not be set at all

Comment: @Lighthart New images only